# How to create a method that gives me a data from a mysql table in the console?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to read data from mysql form a specific table call Menu this table contain four rows I just need to read 4 rows only like item name, price, type, category as to Print it in console in a form of String Like a table view

I tried to create a method do this but I failed, like this method

```
public static void getMenuItems(String tableName) {
    try {
        setConnection();
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;

        String strSelect = "select from " + tableName;
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(strSelect);
        // make the selection at the last row
        rs.last();
        int c = rs.getRow();
        rs.beforeFirst();

        String values[] = new String[c];

        while (rs.next()) {
            int i = 0;
            values[i] = rs.getString(1);
            i++;
        }
        con.close();
        System.out.println(values);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Tools.msgBox(e.getMessage());
    }
```

and this is my Menu.Class

```
public class Menu implements mainData{
    private int Menu_Id;
    private String Name;
    private float Price;
    private String Type;
    private String Category;

    public int getMenu_Id() {
        return Menu_Id;
    }

    public void setMenu_Id(int Menu_Id) {
        this.Menu_Id = Menu_Id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return Price;
    }

    public void setPrice(float Price) {
        this.Price = Price;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return Type;
    }

    public void setType(String Type) {
        this.Type = Type;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return Category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String Category) {
        this.Category = Category;
    }
           //have here some method
.....................................
//Here is a method called getCustomRows
    @Override
    public void getCustomRows(String statement, JTable table) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Comment: *I failed*: what makes you think that? You get an exception, right? Then why not reading its message and stack trace? Surely it will tell you what is wrong, and where?

Comment: Yeah  I Actually got nullException point when I ran project as the msgBox said that No Suitable driver found  for jdbc..........
how ever I installed MySQL JDBC @ cricket_007

Comment: So, maybe you should think about fixing that, by downloading the driver and adding it to the classpath. Or at least by googling the error message you get. Error messages give useful information. Read them.

Comment: I tried that and find that am didn't instal the jdbc library I followed the steps but I have the same exception.... If u need me to show u all code it's ok @cricket_007

Comment: Why are you tagging me?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database/2840358#2840358

Comment: Am So Sorry I Need to tag @JB Nizet but I taged you wrongly am sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple columns, not just a single string. (At least, if you did `SELECT * FROM` in your query)

Make a `Menu values[] = new Menu[c];`

Assign that in a loop

```
 for (int i = 0; rs.next(); i++) {
        Menu m = new Menu();
        // m.setName(rs.getString(1));
        values[i] = m;
 }
```